# why have I a reputation going up on meta programmers when I've no activity on meta programmers?

Tags: discussion

Well I do now. I've some activity here obviously but not before this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All meta sites share reputation with their parent sites: the only exception is [Meta.StackOverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). Any reputation you get on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) transfers here, and you receive no reputation for activity here.

Comment: Why did you bother answering this question then? ;-)

Comment: Why is my reptuation here 10 points higher here than on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) despite no activity here?